# Active Bootstrap Tab Looses Its Index on DropDown SelectedIndexChanged event?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

> Blockquote
>   I'm using Bootstrap TabPane,I have two Tabs, But if there is any 'Auto post back' event Fires I loose my current tab index and goes to first tab which is by default active.
>   I Tried Javascript Found on codeproject but its working fine for button click that they send as demo , when i put drop-down into their code it stops working,
>   Hidden fields value is Comes null on if(this.ispostback){ TabName.Value = Request.Form[TabName.UniqueID];}

My second tab will only be visible to Admin i have to hide it server side too . i want to learn both way server side and client side

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav-tabs a, .nav-tabs a:hover, .nav-tabs a:focus
        {
            outline: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 500px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px">
        <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li><a href="#personal" aria-controls="personal" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#employment" aria-controls="employment" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Employment</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 20px">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="personal">
                    This is Personal Information Tab
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="employment">
                    This is Employment Information Tab
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="TabName" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var tabName = $("[id*=TabName]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=TabName]").val() : "personal";
            $('#Tabs a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
            $("#Tabs a").click(function () {
                $("[id*=TabName]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
            });
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my Code behind `**

```
   public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString);
    MySqlConnection con2 = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            TabName.Value = Request.Form[TabName.UniqueID];
        }
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            CrmNo();
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void FillDDl()
    {
      //This code will Fill my Dropdown on page load
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery to call the tabs by a hash. This way the proper tab will stay selected.

If you're calling your js inside of your head tag in your html you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (location.hash != '') {
        $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    }
    else {
        $('a[role="tab"]:first').tab('show');
    }


    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));
        } else {
            location.hash = '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
        }
    });
});
```

If you're calling your js in the body of the document, then you can simply do it like this.

```
if (location.hash != '') {
    $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
else
{
    $('a[role="tab"]:first').tab('show');
}


$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if (history.pushState) {
        history.pushState(null, null, '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));
    } else {
        location.hash = '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    }
});
```

What this js code should do is adjust the URL so that it has the id of the tab has a hash value of the url. This will make sure that the tab stays selected during postback.

You will of course need to make sure that this code is below your call to your jquery js and your bootstrap js file for it to work properly.